# Why does a newly created snowflake role has access to all existing databases?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I used the following statements:

```
USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
CREATE ROLE TEST_ROLE;
CREATE USER TEST_USER PASSWORD='PASSWORD', DEFAULT_ROLE='TEST_ROLE', DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE='MY_WH';
GRANT ROLE TEST_ROLE TO TEST_USER;
```

When I login with the TEST_USER, the user has access to all existing databases/schemas/tables/views. How come?

Comment: All new roles inherit from the PUBLIC role. TEST_ROLE probably is able to see in these objects only what PUBLIC can see too.

Comment: I've also seen this where PUBLIC is made the owner of the DB objects.  You don't want to do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour if the PUBLIC role was granted access to all your database objects.

By default, all users belong to the PUBLIC role.

You may check the privileges of the TEST_ROLE with this grant statement, which lists all privileges and roles granted to the role:

```
show grants to role TEST_ROLE;
```

and lists all users and roles to which the role has been granted:

```
show grants of role TEST_ROLE;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the case, indeed. Revoking all of that access from PUBLIC role made things normal.